# how to hide a li when a radio is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

once the object is clicked and the li containing a div with radio buttons is shown it does not hide nor does the radio on click close the li.

please see the code example below. think im not targeting the correct objects/ class to do what i want. should i use id's instead of the css class name.?

```
//click to show li (in css i have put display to none)
        $('div.ribbonBoxarrow').click(function() {
        $('.ribbonBoxarrow li').show('medium');
        return false;
      });
// once you leave the div (works thanks kevin. selctor missing
        $('.ribbonBoxtab').mouseleave(function() {
        $('ribbonBoxarrow li').hide('slow');
        return false;
      });
//if a radio buttn is clicked the hide li still not working
        $("input[name='domain_ext']").each(function() {
        $('.ribbonBoxarrow li').hide('slow');
        return false;
      });
```

css-----

```
/* Ribbon radio drop box */
.ribbontableBox {
    width: 62px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.ribbontableBox:hover {
    width: 62px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    border: 1px solid #72B8E2;
    background: #AED5F4;
}

.ribbonBoxtext {
    width:52px;
    height:50px;
    float: left;
}

.ribbonBoxtext ul {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
}

.ribbonBoxarrow {
    width: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
 }
.ribbonBoxarrow ul {
    width: 10px;
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    background: #ffffff;
}
.ribbonBoxarrow ul:hover {
    background: #AED5F4;
}

.ribbonBoxarrow li  {
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 110px;
    width: 120px;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    top:45px;
    left: -57px;
    border: 1px solid #72B8E2;
}
/*.ribbonBoxarrow ul:hover > li {
    background: #ffffff;
    height: 110px;
    width: 120px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top:45px;
    left: -57px;
    border: 1px solid #72B8E2;
}*/

.ribbonBoxtab {
    background: #555555;
    border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    height: 0px;
    width: 180px;
    position: relative;
    display:inherit;
}


</style>
```

html-----------------

```
<div class="ribbonBoxarrow">
  <ul class="ribbonBoxarrow">
        <li> 

        <div class="ribbonBoxtab">
          <table class="domain_ext_table">
            <tr>
              <td><label>
                <input type="radio" name="domain_ext" value="all"/>
                <span>All</span></label></td>
              <td><label>
                <input type="radio" name="domain_ext" value=".co.uk"/>
                <span>.co.uk</span></label></td>
              </tr>
             <tr>
             <td><label>
                <input type="radio" name="domain_ext" value=".com"/>
               <span>.com</span></label></td>
              <td><label>
                <input type="radio" name="domain_ext" value=".rnet"/>
                <span>.net</span></label></td> 
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td><label>
                <input type="radio" name="domain_ext" value=".briz"/>
                <span>.biz</span></label></td>
              <td><label>
                <input type="radio" name="domain_ext" value=".orrg"/>
               <span>.rorg</span></label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td><label>
                <input type="radio" name="domain_ext" value=".trr"/>
                <span>.org.ruk</span></label></td> 
               <td><label>
                <input type="radio" name="domain_ext" value=".rrrt"/>
                <span>.thh</span></label></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
  </li>
  </ul>        
</div>
```

Comment: can you add some example of your html also.

Comment: ive tried $("input[type='radio']").each(function() {
         $('ribbonBoxarrow li').hide('slow');
         return false;
          }); but no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is missing the `.` in the class selector.  Also I changed `.each` to `.click` for the radio event handlers.  If your loading this code on page load you should wrap it with `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //click to show li (in css i have put display to none)
            $('div.ribbonBoxarrow').click(function() {
                $('.ribbonBoxarrow li').show('medium');
                return false;
            });
    // once you leave the div (which is contained in the above li hide.
            $('.ribbonBoxtab').mouseleave(function() {
                $('.ribbonBoxarrow li').hide('slow'); //missing .
                return false;
            });
    //if a radio buttn is clicked the hide li
            $("input[name='domain_ext']").click(function() { //changed .each to .click
                $('.ribbonBoxarrow li').hide('slow'); //missing .
                return false;
            });
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/3wkpZ/

Comment: that has corrected the mouse leave but the onclick for the radio is still giving me problems.

Comment: @alwayslearning Thats because there isn't a `click` event handler attached. I updated changing `.each()` to `.click`

Comment: thanks kevin should sleep, must finish this, still not doing it. tried it with $("input[type='radio']").click(function() { no luck

Comment: @alawayslearning I created a fiddle and the event handler on the radio is working although the css is a bit off.  Are you executing this script on page load? You may need to wrap all of this in `document.ready`

Comment: have all code running after $(document).ready(function() {
 in a seperate .js file. the li now closes with the alert. but would rather it just closed. thanks for the fiddle and help. css is off as i am dressing the radios up using jquery.